# XPath in XML contains an element with two values

Tags: xml, xpath

So I have an xml that has this specific line:

```
<XPath>self::CS[contains(@channelID, 'RCS') and contains(@channelID, 'ISDN') and @available = 'yes']</XPath>
```

My question is how can I rewrite this and can @channelID have two values?

I tried like this but with no success:

```
< CS channelID="RCS" channelID="ISDN" available="yes"/>
```

Comment: Does the answer to [How to add the same attribute multiple times to an Element Tag in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12664170/1115360) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

channelID `contains` means if it found both sub-string as RCS and ISDN and it is bind with `and` operator means the ID must contains both sub-string as RCS and ISDN.

so id channelID is having string as RCSISDN or RCSANDISDN etc it will work